# How to store a bi-directional graph using map in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, data-structures, tree, c++17

I am trying to store a bi-directional graph as an adjacency list using `std::map<int,vector<int>>`. The idea here is to store n nodes, from 1 to n in this map.
The input is given as `u v`, which denotes an edge between node u and node v. We get n such inputs on n lines.
My code for storing the graph:

```
    int u,v;
    map<int,vector<int>> graph();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> u >> v;
        graph[u].push_back(v);
        graph[v].push_back(u);
    }
```

This should work, but it gave me errors when complied with C++ 14. I then compiled this with C++ 17 and the errors still persists.
Errors(as displayed on my terminal):

```
/home/chirag/chiragC/forces/try.cpp: In function ‘void solve()’:
/home/chirag/chiragC/forces/try.cpp:68:10: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   graph[u].push_back(v);
          ^
/home/chirag/chiragC/forces/try.cpp:68:12: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘*(graph + ((sizetype)u))’, which is of non-class type ‘std::map<int, std::vector<int> >()’
   graph[u].push_back(v);
            ^~~~~~~~~
/home/chirag/chiragC/forces/try.cpp:69:10: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   graph[v].push_back(u);
          ^
/home/chirag/chiragC/forces/try.cpp:69:12: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘*(graph + ((sizetype)v))’, which is of non-class type ‘std::map<int, std::vector<int> >()’
   graph[v].push_back(u);
            ^~~~~~~~~
[Finished in 1.5s with exit code 1]
```

I feel the script I am using to store the graph is correct, as my friend was able to run this code completely fine on his system. I don't know why it is giving errors.

My System: debian 10

Headers used: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

Some info on my Compiler:

```
chirag@debian10:~/chiragC/forces$ ls /usr/bin | grep g++
arm-none-eabi-g++
avr-g++
g++
g++-8
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-8
chirag@debian10:~/chiragC/forces$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

chirag@debian10:~/chiragC/forces$
```

Comment: Your bug is here: `map<int,vector<int>> graph();` you declared a function called graph returning this map.  Remove the parenthesis.

Comment: Also avoid using maps for creating a graph. Implementing graph algorithms would be complicated as hell. Also as a piece of advice, learn c++ classes and objects to efficiently use STL containers. Sorting, inserting, etc operations would be breeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is that you are trying to make a function named `graph()` remove the parenthesis then all will be fine.

Comment: What a noob I am.